# Convergence of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{1}{1+|x|^{k}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

If I'm not mistaken, the integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{1}{1+|x|^{k}}dx$$
has a condition (on $k$) for convergence which depends on the dimension $n$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But not only I always forget about what is this condition but also I've never understood how to prove that this conditions must be satisfied. Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to polar.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {dx\over 1 + |x|^k}
= c_n\int_0^\infty {r^{n-1}\, dr\over 1 + r^k},$$
where $c_n$ is just the surface area of $S^{n-1}$
in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: So easy and it didn't ocurred do me! Thanks. So the condition for convergence would be $k \ge n$?

Comment: @MathMath $k > n$, actually. Integral diverges for $k = n$.

Comment: Ops, my bad. I actually meant $k \ge n+1$.

Comment: @MathMath $n-1-k<-1\implies k>n$